# How i can programmatically get all the SharePoint team-sites?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In my SharePoint site in "SharePoint admin center" page (Admin->Sharepoint) i have list of the teamsites of my organization. How i can get this list programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a list of site collections,  you could use [SharePoint Online Administration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132908%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to manage SharePoint Online (SPO).

PowerShell example:

```
#Connect to SPO
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential usernam@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
#Retrieve all site collections
Get-SPOSite
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is code that gets you the names of your lists:

References:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using SharePointclientObj = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

Code:

```
        string clientContext = "http://yourteamsiteslocation";
        List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();

        //Get a context
        using (SharePointclientObj.ClientContext ctx = new SharePointclientObj.ClientContext(clientContext))
        {
            //Get the site
            SharePointclientObj.Web site = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(site);
            //Get Lists
            ctx.Load(site.Lists);
            //Query
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            //Fill List                

            foreach (SharePointclientObj.List list in site.Lists)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
                tableNames.Add(list.Title);
                //listBox1.Items.Add(list.Title);
            }
        }
```